# ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, api

Estoy tratando de recorrer un array en Angular con NgFor pero me aparece este error en consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:
HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor= "let product of listarproducts">
                        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.category}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.location}</td>
                        <td>{{product.price | currency: 'USD' }}</td>
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from '../models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/products/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } // Insertamos la clase Http client 

getproducts(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.url);
}
}
```

Component .ts

```
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listar-products',
  templateUrl: './listar-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listar-products.component.css']
})
export class ListarProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  listarproducts: Product[] = [];

  constructor(private _productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProducts();
  }

  getProducts() {
    this._productService.getproducts().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.listarproducts = data;
    }, error =>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
}
```

Es la primera vez que hago una llamada a una API desde Angular y no encuentro donde está mal, si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: lo que pasa es que a tu `listarproducts` le estas pasando un `Objeto` si te fijas en tu respuesta en el primer corchete te dice `Object`, luego te trae el `Array`, solucion es igualar a `data.obj`, si quieres probar haz un `console.log(typeof data)` y veras.

Comment: @AndresAbadia Muchas gracias, ya lo pude solucionar ✔✔

Comment: @AndresAbadia cómo solucionaste?

Comment: @AndresAbadia cómo solucionaste?

Comment: @kintela el primer comentario se explica el por qué , VSacudato fue el que comentó que ya lo había podido solucionar

Comment: @AndresAbadia gracias pero es que no entiendo la solución yo estoy teniendo el mismo problema https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ymtnrw?file=src/app/app.component.ts y según interpreto lo que dices es que asigne al suscribirse no a data sin a la propiedad de data que tiene el array pero en mi caso me da error

Comment: @kintela hice un fork de tu [proyecto](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cesfab?file=src/app/app.component.ts) puedes revisar los cambios y comparalo con el tuyo habian ciertas cosas mal declaradas

Comment: @AndresAbadia gracias pero ahora no recibo nada del web api como puedes comprobar. El web API esta publicado en Azure y si miras lo que devuelve https://boletusapi.azurewebsites.net/api/responsables yo eso no lo veo en consola lo que veo es este error Http failure response for https://boletusapi.azurewebsites.net/api/responsables. y lo que sigo sin entender es por que mi controlador devuelve esto return await _context.Ofertas.ToListAsync();, es decir, una lista de Ofertas, pero luego Angular recoge un solo objeto con id y values